# errors while updating my PC

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, upgrade, updates

I have searched the whole internet including reading everything on google/askubuntu/all ubuntu communities), tried all the possible solution and still didn't figure it out (but I am not google so my indexing and searching algorithm skills might not be that good)

anyways to the point. I am trying to run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade`.

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not installed
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

then i ran `apt --fix-broken install` .. and got these results

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/29.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 147 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 298882 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i tried all the tricks like `apt clean`/`remove`/`dist upgrade`/whatever `apt` i found on the net without luck.

any help is really appricated.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035409/installing-nvidia-drivers-on-18-04 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error sometime back and if fixed it using a package named `aptitude`.

Run this `sudo apt install aptitude` 
Then run `sudo aptitude upgrade`

It will give you possible solutions ignore the first and use the second.

Hope this will work for you too.