# NVIDIA Driver Error Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

Hi I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and tried to update my drivers but keeps on getting this error. I tried purging all nvidia related drivers and reinstalling it but still doesn't work.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libnvidia-ifr1-430: Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 but it is not installed
libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386: Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 but it is not installed
nvidia-driver-430: Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not installed
                   Depends: nvidia-dkms-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-compute-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-decode-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-encode-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-utils-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
```

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r85F.png)
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmo4Z.png)

Comment: Try to install `libnvidia-gl-430` or 1st. see if another version is already installed, if so remove it. `apt-cache policy libnvidia-gl-* |grep Installed:`

Comment: @doug I added the image results of what I did. I keep going round in circles fixing it and starting to be so confused because no fix online help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing nvidia drivers on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035409/installing-nvidia-drivers-on-18-04)