# Lock screen blur missing in 20.04

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, ubuntu-gnome, gdm, 20.04

After upgrading to **Ubuntu 20.04** featuring **Gnome 3.36**, the lock screen displays a solid purple color, instead of the blur-over-wallpaper effect. How can I fix this?

Gnome 3.36 removes the separate configuration for lock screen wallpaper / background, and replaces it with a feature that uses the existing desktop background and applies a blur effect on top, as [discussed and as seen here](https://blogs.gnome.org/shell-dev/2020/02/18/login-and-unlock-in-gnome-shell-3-36/). However, this is not the case on my instance.

My instance shows a solid purple background on the lock screen, while the system settings app correctly removes the option for two wallpapers and only allows the user to select one. Opening up Gnome Tweaks, however, shows two wallpaper settings (desktop, lockscreen), but the lockscreen setting is ignored.

### Attempted Steps

- After the upgrade to **20.04** I re-enabled a repo that I thought was for the PopOS icon package and updated accordingly. However, looking through my installed packages I saw there were a number that were forked from **Ubuntu** and versioned like `*ubuntu1pop0`. This may (or may not) be the cause of the problem, I'm unsure. I downgraded all the packages I could find back to Ubuntu versions, and disabled the repo.
- I purged and reinstalled `gnome-shell` and `gdm3`
- I tried using `update-alternatives --auto gdm3` and other `update-alternatives` commands, but no luck and I don't exactly know what I'm doing with that.

Comment: related: [remove-blur-effect-on-lock-screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247024/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you're using a NVidia GPU? If yes, open `nvidia-settings` and try test between the 3 profiles.

I lose the blur (and usually all dialogs shading) when I try the "**NVIDIA On-Demand**" profile.

Later I realized this was happening because the NVidia drivers were not properly updated (I was facing an `apt divert` error like described on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035409/installing-nvidia-drivers-on-18-04).

Comment: Yes, I was using the `on-demand` profile. I would have never figured this out, ever. Thanks! Not sure why this is a problem, but I'm not going to poke the bear anymore.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but after employing this solution, I no longer get 'nightlight' functionality. The toggle is in settings, but the screen doesn't change. Thoughts?

Comment: Mine still works, but I'm under the Intel profile. I didn't test under NVidia "full".

Comment: Turns out it was unrelated. I switched to `intel` profile and `nvidia` with restarts in between and the functionality returned. Must've been something else.

Comment: And how about "NVIDIA On-Demand"?

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to enable gdm3 and disable lightdm.
Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and select gdm3 then `sudo reboot`. Initial lock screen appears purple but when locking after login the blur effect is active.